# Get precise return type from a TypeTag and a method

Tags: scala, reflection, scala-reflect

Say I have

```
trait Foo[T] { def bar: Bar[T] }
```

and want to obtain return type of `bar` when called on a `Foo[Int]` (i.e. `Bar[Int]` in this case) from the type tag of `Foo[Int]` and the name `"bar"` (we can assume there are no overloads or we can tell them apart). Can this be done done with scala-reflect?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is this close to what you want (using `asSeenFrom`)?

```
val tt = typeTag[Foo[Int]]

scala> tt.tpe
    .members
    .find(_.name.toString == "bar").get
    .asMethod
    .returnType
    .asSeenFrom(tt.tpe, tt.tpe.typeSymbol)

res68: reflect.runtime.universe.Type = Bar[Int]
```

I've of course thrown type-safety out the window. Slightly better:

```
scala> tt.tpe
     .members
     .find(_.name.toString == "bar")
     .filter(_.isMethod)
     .map(_.asMethod.returnType.asSeenFrom(tt.tpe, tt.tpe.typeSymbol))

res74: Option[reflect.runtime.universe.Type] = Some(Bar[Int])
```

Comment: Looks like it, thanks! I won't mark this as accepted just yet, since I will only be able to test it on Friday.

Comment: Yes, there's Type.asSeenFrom and there's also Symbol.typeSignatureIn/infoIn, which is implemented on top of the same infrastructure.

Comment: @EugeneBurmako How would you use `typeSignatureIn`? If I replace `asSeenFrom(...)` with `.typeSymbol.typeSignatureIn(tt.tpe)` it doesn't seem to return the same thing. I'm guessing I'm not using it correctly?

Comment: I also tried the same (leaving the comment so that I get notified).

Answer (score 2):

In case someone runs into this in the future: with this variation

```
trait Foo[T] { def bar: Option[T] }
trait Bar[T] extends Foo[T]

val tt = typeTag[Bar[Int]]
```

I had to slightly change @m-z's answer:

```
val m = tt.tpe
  .member(newTermName("bar"))
  .asMethod

m.returnType
  .asSeenFrom(tt.tpe, m.owner)
```

Comment: This solved my use case and it looks like it's the generally correct way of doing this - thanks a lot!